# Windows XP PDF Metadata vanished on other machine

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-xp

I need to develop c# program to read the metadata (Title, Author..) of PDF file which was added on Windows XP machine (That's Client Machine restricted to access directly)

When those file copied to other windows 10 or even other win XP machine ( via Email in zip compressed File) then those property becomes blank, and not able to fetch any values.

I have used iTextSharp, PDFSharp, SyncFusion library. All are not able to fetch those information which was visible on client's windows XP machine.

If anyone faced this scenario, please share valuable efforts

Comment: Where do you see those metadata on the XP machine?

Comment: @mkl  PDF File-> Property -> Summary 

Here we can see Auther, Subject, Title..

Comment: Googl'ing around a bit it looks like you need to install a PDF specific Column Handler or Property Handler to display the PDF document metadata in windows explorer and in windows file properties. Probably on your Windows XP machine such an explorer extension was installed while it isn't installed on the other machines you tested. See e.g. [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/602536).